# How can I pass an IP address used in a function as command line argument to argument parser?

Tags: python, argparse

I have this function that is pinging a server to get its response. I want to to able to give the IP address used in the function to argument parser as a command line argument instead of hardcoding it or taking it as user input.
Currently the function looks like:

```
def get_sipresponse():
        var = input("Enter Opensips IP: ")
        p = sys.path.append("/home/asad.javed/")
        response = sip.ping(var)
        response.get('Status')
        print(response)
        return p, response
```

My main function where I am using argument parser looks like:

```
def main():
        parser = ap.ArgumentParser()
        parser.add_argument('-s', '--start', help='start script', action='store_true')
        parser.add_argument('--getOSresponse', help='Opensips response', action='store_true')

        args = parser.parse_args()

        elif args.start
                for k,v in reversed_dictionary.items():
                        print(v, "=", k);time.sleep(5);
                        proc = subprocess.call([k], shell=True);time.sleep(5);
                        if proc != 0:
                                if proc < 0:
                                        print("Killed by signal!", -proc)
                                else:
                                        print("\nReturn code: \n", proc)
                        else:
                                print("\nSuccess\n");get_sipresponse()

        elif args.getOSresponse:
                get_sipresponse()
```

Comment: Why can't you just add an argument to the arg parser for the IP address and pass it to `get_sipresponse()` as a function parameter?

Comment: How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your main, under the setup for other arguments in the arg parser, add this line:

```py
parser.add_argument('--ip')
```

Then change `get_sipresponse()` to this:

```py
def get_sipresponse(ip):
        p = sys.path.append("/home/asad.javed/")
        response = sip.ping(ip)
        response.get('Status')
        print(response)
        return p, response
```

Lastly from `main`, you can call `get_sipresponse` like this:

```py
get_sipresponse(args.ip)
```

Comment: How would I be giving the IP address?

Comment: Sorry I am new to Python and I am getting an error when I give an IP with the argument --ip 10.xx.xx.xxx

Comment: `def get_sipresponse(ip):`
        `p = sys.path.append("/home/asad.javed/")`
        `response = sip.ping(ip)`
        `response.get('Status')`
        `print(response)`
        `return p, response`

Comment: The code is working as expected on my end, are you providing a valid IP address for the `ping` function? Also please when asking for help when you are "getting an error" provide the error message otherwise there is very little I can do to help you.

Comment: In the main function I am giving `parser.add_argument('--ip')`. After `args= parser.parse_args()` I am giving  `get_sipresponse(args.ip)`. Now I need to use it in args.start and when I run the script like **./managerInterface -s --ip 10.10.9.1** I am getting an error and it says **unrecognized argument**. I am also passing get_sipresponse(ip) in args.start.

Comment: From the above code I have changed it to `elif args.start and elif args.ip:` and then the rest of the code as it is and in the end I have changed the `get_sipresponse()` function to `get_sipresponse(ip)`. I am executing it as **./managerInterface.py -s --ip 10.xx.x.x** but not able to execute it.

Comment: If you are running your script without running `python` , It appears to me that your application has some kind of wrapper script that may be passing arguments differently to the actual python code. I have demonstrated how to use arg parser for this and confirmed it works based on the code you have provided. It appears that this bug lies elsewhere in your application and at this point I can no longer provide assistance.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Andrew Harelson for the help. I figured out the mistake I was making at my end. Its running as I want it to now.

Answer (score 0):

If you return a "dict" from your `get_sipresponse()`:

```
def get_sipresponse():
        var = input("Enter Opensips IP: ")
        p = sys.path.append("/home/asad.javed/")
        response = sip.ping(var)
        response.get('Status')
        print(response)
        return {'ip': var , 
                'path': p, 
                'resp': response}
```

Then you can use it in your `main()` function.

```
def main():
  target_ip = get_sipresponse()['ip']
  ......
  .....
  ...
```

Comment: This does not retrieve the ip from the command line, this just returns the hardcoded/user inputed IP address back after the method call.